# I have created a home page using reactstrap and hashrouter. But the router views are not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem
} from 'reactstrap';

import Home from "./Home";
import Shop from "./Shop";
import About from "./About";
import Banner from "./Banner";
import Footer from "./Footer";



class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">iFashion</NavbarBrand>
            <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
            <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
              <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink to="/shop">Shop</NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                  <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                    Options
                </DropdownToggle>
                  <DropdownMenu right>
                    <DropdownItem>
                      Option 1
                  </DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem>
                      Option 2
                  </DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem divider />
                    <DropdownItem>
                      Reset
                  </DropdownItem>
                  </DropdownMenu>
                </UncontrolledDropdown>
              </Nav>
            </Collapse>
          </Navbar>

          <div className="content">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/shop" component={Shop} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          </div>
          <Banner />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </HashRouter>

    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

I'm new to **Reactjs** and I'm trying to create a **home page**. Also, I'm using **hash router**, to render the views. But the problem is: the Hash Router was working before the **reactstrap classes** are called. But once after including the **reactstrap classes**, the views are not **rendering**. In the console window, I'm getting this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NytEO.png) . What is the solution?

Comment: are you getting any console errors ?

Comment: I have included the errors in the post.

Comment: why are you passing `exact` here ? remove its from `<NavItem>
                  <NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink>
                </NavItem>`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `exact` from this below code.

```
<NavItem>
   <NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink>
</NavItem>
```

update above code with.

```
<NavItem>
   <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
</NavItem>
```

Comment: have you removed `exact ` from `NavLink ` ?

Comment: it should resolve, else check somewhere you are passing `exact` while redirecting.

Comment: no. It's still not working. I'm again coding from beginning. If it goes well, I will ley you know.

Comment: am sure its silly mistake, just review your code once before starting from beginning.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. There was a conflict between NavLink from 'react-dom' and NavLink from 'reactstrap'. But we can rename it "NavLink as navlink" and while implementing we can write as <NavLink to =" " tag{navlink}>Home</NavLink>. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: that sounds great swathi

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to pass **exact** to `NavLink`. This prop should be passed only to the `Route` component. The `NavLink` thinks that it's a simple prop and asks you to put some attribute inside.
React routing is a pretty big theme for learning. The best tutorial for that is [React Router training](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route).
Please go through it and you'll see a whole picture.